# How to export Firestore subcollection to Google Sheet?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm trying to connect my Firestore with Google Sheet through Zapier, but there is always an error `We couldn’t find a record`. In the Zapier, I can only select my collection `forms`, but the data I want to connect to Sheet is from the subcollection of `forms` which is `form`. Anyone knows how?

Comment: I've tried `forms/{USER_ID}/form` to access my form subcollection.

Comment: Did you check your Cloud Firestore rules? You can also include your Firestore rules in your Question and other information like codes/Firestore database.